# Do I separate the view code in Django?

Tags: python, django

I started out with Django some days ago and I have now made a project and an app (named questions).

The web application I make is for serving questions from my database and I want the users to be able to submit new questions and so on. I also added the admin interface app which was pretty cool:)

Now I wonder how I structure the code. Should I put all view functions belonging to the entire web application in the views.py in the questions-app?

Additional question: If I want users to register before adding questions (I have not figured out how to do this yet) do I use the admin app and make a custom group with permissions for this? Or is it bad? Is it better to keep the admin app for admins only and register/login  users separate?

EDIT: I guess this relates to the second question? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-profiles

Is this a separate thing from the admin, or does it store the users together with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you application is as small as displaying questions by retrieving them from the database & receiving answers. You will be fine with just one views.py

But, when the projects are big, you should create a separate app for each functionality.

For ex, if you have a website to sell products, you will have a separate app for Feedback, Complaints, Marketplace etc.

To start a separate app, please see the option [`startapp` in django-manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination).

To see the user authentication, see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/). See, how user authentication is done [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests). If you have the patience of reading the doc, you will get it anyways.

Comment: But still Gmail is pretty large, so are all view functions inside views.py?

Comment: @Pjotr Sorry. I just wrote it to tell you the classification. See another example.

Comment: Then it make more sense. However if I have an application named "questions" now, where I have defined the models related to question (Question, answer, category). And then I want to have an app named Feedback....do I only define a Feedback model inside models.py and use the question models from the other app then?

Comment: @Pjotr I have only done 1 project using django & that too I did in my semester courses so I will leave that to be answered by more experienced guys. Meanwhile, have a look at [this](http://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&site=webhp&source=hp&q=use%20models%20from%20another%20app%20django&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=669988a1c8acab68&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=669988a1c8acab68&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=791)